# Java 1.6, Calendar and Java cache

Tags: java, caching, jboss, calendar, timezone

This is my first question, but is a important question (and strange question). Sorry if my english is not good, I dont speak it often.

I have a big problem when I want to get a Calendar.getInstance(). I'm using JBoss 3.2.5 and I'm creating a .war app, Java 1.6.0.25 (with Java 1.7 get the same problem) and Windows 7 Enterprise. I execute the app with Java Web Start.

The code of my aplication (where the problem appears) is here:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + c.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
    System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + c.getTimeZone().getID());
    System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + c.getTime());
    System.out.println(" ------------------- ");
      ...
```

As you can see, the problem is when the application starts.

When I enable the Java cache in Control Panel (Java->General->Temp files->Configuration->Keep temporary files on my computer) I get this result:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Hora de Europa Central
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Europe/Paris
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Thu May 16 16:37:18 CEST 2013
```

BUT when I disable the Java cache, the result is completly different, I get this:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Hora Universal Coordinada
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> UTC
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Thu May 16 14:41:48 UTC 2013
```

And that's my problem, I need always the same result, the first, because I need the GMT+1 and, as we are in summer, we have an +1 extra, then we have GMT+2.

If I call the next sentence I always get a correct TimeZone:

```
System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
```

This:

```
Europe/Paris
```

I don't know how I can fix this problem, I've tried to cast TimeZones, Calendars, DateFormats but I can't get the correct time, always I get a UTC time.

With Java 1.7 the behaivor is different, I enable cache but if is clean, it has a bad behaivor but only the first time, the second works fine (unless you clean the Java cache again).

Any idea to fix this???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you care about timezone, the server live in GMT.

Comment: Yes, but when is UTC I can't get a GMT Calendar with his TimeZone correct.

Comment: Jboss by default uses system timezone, but database is using UTC. Try with `-Duser.timezone=GMT`.

Comment: BTW in the calendar you can set timezone explicitly.

Comment: I tried, but I could not reproduce this.  I get the same time zone regardless of that setting.

Comment: Sorry for my delay. Yes, I set the timezone in the calendar with .setTimeZone but It dont change the time, the TIME_OFFSET sais 360000 (that's good) and sais Europe/Paris but when I show the time is not reflected the time change, It shows the same (and is not 360000, it should be 720000 because in summer is +2). I can't use the -Duser.timezone because the program is internationality and the clients can't put their timezone manually. I'll try with the JBoss (is a good idea). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another example, if I put - 
String zona = System.getProperty("user.timezone");
Calendar hereTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zona));
System.out.println(""+hereTime.getTime());
System.out.println(""+hereTime.getTimeZone().getDisplayName());
 - 
The result is - 
Mon May 20 07:39:32 UTC 2013
Hora de Europa Central
 - 
The TimeZone works, but the time is UTC :(